# Horizontal concat in Daru::DataFrame?

Tags: ruby, daru

I know that by `Daru::DataFrame#concat` one can concatenate dataframes, appending the argument df to the bottom of the caller df.

Now I want to achieve what is `df.concat(other, axis=1)` in Pandas.  In other words, given I have two dataframes where the index are the same, append one df to the right of the other df, resulting df having same index but the concatenated vectors.

Is this possible by some method?  Or do I need to iterate and add each columns in for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for possibly?

`data_frame = data_frame.join(jobs_data_frame, how: :left, on: [:user_id])`

Comment: I'm looking for way to join on `the index`, not `a column`...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`add_vector`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/daru/0.1.3.1/Daru%2FDataFrame:add_vector) method.

For eg:

```
2.6.3 :001 > require 'daru'

2.6.3 :007 > df = Daru::DataFrame.new([[00,01,02], [10,11,12],[20,21,22]], order: ["a", "b", "c"])
 => #<Daru::DataFrame(3x3)>
       a   b   c
   0   0  10  20
   1   1  11  21
   2   2  12  22
2.6.3 :008 > df.add_vector("d", [30, 31, 32])
 => [30, 31, 32]
2.6.3 :009 > df
 => #<Daru::DataFrame(3x4)>
       a   b   c   d
   0   0  10  20  30
   1   1  11  21  31
   2   2  12  22  32
```

Although you'll have to add each vector separately.

Comment: Thanks, It would be nice if you could show code to concat df1 and df2.